# The differential of inclusion from S^{2} to R^{3}

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential

I've found this question on Loring Tu's "Introduction to Manifolds", numbered 11.4 and titled **"Differential of the inclusion map"**

> On the upper hemisphere of the unit sphere $S^{2}$ we have the coordinate map $\phi = (u,v)$, where $u(a,b,c) = a, \ v(a,b,c) = b$ 
> Let $i: S^{2} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ be the inclusion, and $i_*$ it's differential. 
> Calculate:
> $$
> i_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}), \ \ 
> i_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}) 
> $$
> in terms of  $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, where x,y,z are the standard coordinates

I've fiddled with it a bit, and the closest I've came is something like:

$$i_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial u})(x) = (\frac{\partial}{\partial u})(x \circ i)  = (\frac{\partial}{\partial u}) (u) = 1\\
i_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial u})(y) = (\frac{\partial}{\partial u})(y \circ i) = 0 \\
i_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial u})(z) = (\frac{\partial}{\partial u}) (z \circ i)
$$

I can't really wrap my head around
calculating $(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}) (z \circ i)$.

Some guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it takes some time to be able to go back and forth between concepts and local expressions in differential geometry, but essentially the pushout of a vector in local expressions is just the chain rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here $z\circ i \circ \phi^{-1}=\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}$ and so

$\frac{\delta}{\delta u} \sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}=$

$=\frac{-u}{\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}}=-\frac{x}{z}$

so that

$i_*(\frac{\delta}{\delta u })=\frac{\delta}{\delta x}-\frac{x}{z}\frac{\delta}{\delta z}$

Similarly

$i_*(\frac{\delta}{\delta v })=\frac{\delta}{\delta y}-\frac{y}{z}\frac{\delta}{\delta z}$

Merry Christmas